# Generation mPDF very Slow on AWS (Serverless Docker) compared to a Ubuntu VPS

Tags: mpdf

I have some big differences in time thats needed to generate a mPDF.
On an AWS (Serverless with Docker) hosted Application it took me 25 seconds to generate a PDF, while that identically same PDF took 5 seconds to generate on a VPS with Ubuntu installed.
The PDF doesn't contain any images, just plain text.

Is there something I can configure on AWS what can speed-up things? Like installing some extra packages in my Docker instance maybe?

Comment: How does your AWS instance performance compare with the VPS? Share more information about the setup.

Comment: Same, both using 4GB. The generation takes around 130MB. So that is enough. It's Serverless.

Comment: On VPS run with Docker? Same image?